# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an error with this C# code they said "Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
where is the mistakes?

```
        Console.Write("Input money : ");
        float money;
        int tax;
        if (money < 10000)
        {
            tax = .05 * money;
        }
        else if (money <= 100000)
        {
            tax = .08 * money;
        }
        else
        {
            tax = .085 * money;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Tax is {0}", tax);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring tax as *int* makes no sense whatsoever.  Use decimal whenever you tinker with monetary values.

Comment: It means exactly what it says: you can't just assign a double value to an integer. You could do an explicit cast to do the assignment, but you have to do it explicitly because the cast could entail information loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your variable tax to double

```
  double tax = 0;
```

Working Code,

```
Console.Write("Input money : ");
float money = Console.Read();          
double tax = 0;
if (money < 10000)
{
    tax = .05 * money;
}
else if (money <= 100000)
{
    tax = .08 * money;
}
else
{
    tax = .085 * money;
}

Console.WriteLine("Tax is {0}", tax);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

`tax` is an `int` and you are trying to assign it a `float` value.

You either have to declare `tax` as a `float` / `double` / `decimal` or somehow round its value.

EDIT: It's also weird how you don't initialize the value of `money`, use `Console.ReadLine()`, and parse its return value